# push notification without firebase

Tags: swift

I want to send cloud messages from Firebase, I added the code, but it's not working right now. Do I need user input so I can use the notification feature? I'm not using the user input feature in my application right now. Do I need to set the firebase user login property to my application to run the notification feature?

My code is this way, but my notification feature doesn't work. I added certificates and handled other transactions fully.

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        completionHandler()
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
            return
        }
        // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // Pass device token to auth
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)

        // Further handling of the device token if needed by the app
        // ...
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

    }

    /// Register for push notifications
    func registerForPushNotification(){

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {

            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}


extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {

    func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {


    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        print(fcmToken)

    }
}
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        //UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(1800)

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])

        self.registerForPushNotification()
}
    func application(_ application : UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
    {
        if FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) ?? false {
            return true
        }
        // other URL handling goes here.
        return false

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answers below :

1. You do not need the Firebase user login property in order to send a push notification. All you will need is the appropriate integration with your Firebase project.
2. To use notification feature, you will need user's consent. I assumed you've handled it in your Swift code.
3. To get it working, check if Firebase integration is done appropriately. e.g. check if GoogleService-info.plist is appropriately added in the project. At times, it shows in the directory but Xcode can't use if it's not logically linked in the project.

Comment: Thank you for your help, my code is this way, but my notification feature is not working. I added certificates and handled other transactions fully.